# Evaluate the integral by reversing the order of integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

I'm having trouble solving for the new limits when I reverse the order of integration for the integral $$\int_{0}^1\int_{x}^1{e^{x\over y}}dydx$$
If someone could help me understand how to solve for the new limits, that would be great. I don't think I'll need help with the integration, it's just the setting up that gives me the most trouble.

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, don't forget to mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your region:

[image]

Notice, it is bounded by the lines $y=0$ and $y=1$, so those are our bounds for $y$.  Next, for any specific $y_0$, we are considering the $x$ values that range from $0$ to $y_0$, so our bounds for $x$ are $0<x<y$.  Is that clear?  The integral becomes:

$$\int_{0}^1\int_0^ye^{\frac{x}{y}}dxdy$$

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture. Start with the inside integral, and think what it looks like when a path going upward is between $x$ and 1 (if it hits $x$ first, it is counted positive; if it hits 1 first, it is counted negative). Then take only the part of that region between $x=0$ and $x=1$.

In this case, it is a triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,1)$. If you want to switch the limits you need to think of where a path moving to the right enters the region, and where it exits.

Comment: No problem! ...